# Change Background Color with Angular

Tags: css, html, angularjs, background

I know this has got to be simple - I'm trying to change the background color of the div based on the variable {{site.bool}} being true or false.

```
<div class="list-group-item col-md-8 pull-left" ng-repeat="site in list.links">
   <h3>
        {{site.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">{{site.url}}</em>
        {{site.description}}
        <product-tabs></product-tabs>
   </h3>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where is site.bool in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a class to the div dynamically like this:

```
<div ng-class="{cool: trueOrFalseVariable}"> ... </div>
```

That will apply a `cool` class to the div depending on if `trueOrFalseVariable` is true or false. Then it's just a simple matter of setting up the `.cool{}` CSS rule in your stylesheet.

You can read all about `ng-class` [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fapi%2Fng%2Fdirective%2FngClass&ei=hdo1VOqGEeKD8QHS0YCIDg&usg=AFQjCNGjGEX7Q--VXP_kkWmzlCzKazZ8Qg&sig2=0YYzK9MDRg-hoHyEOBBy9A&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw) and you might want to read about [ng-style](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fapi%2Fng%2Fdirective%2FngStyle&ei=kto1VIWWI-bs8QHqsoHgBg&usg=AFQjCNH-2YiRxapKU_4HPT03OeI7DJTQLA&sig2=s9nZhkE-2S5nXiW-xaY-8w&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw) too!